# how to support Arabic language in html page?

Tags: html, ios, xcode6, arabic

I need to load HTML page from URL in my iOS app. The problem that the Arabic characters that are in this html page are shown as strange symbols.

I add `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">` but it dose not change.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I guess there is some encoding problem, but you need to post more detail for us to know .

Comment: Presumably the HTML page you're reading specifies a charset?  Look here for more details: https://www.isoc.org/inet98/proceedings/5f/5f_1.htm

Comment: What encoding does your browser detect the page as?

Answer (score 0):

Add unicode as your support in your html. try using the following in the head of html:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: thanks I add it but it dose not help me. I guess the problem is in the setting of the xcode.What do you thing?? have you other idea to solve it??

Answer (score 0):

The Arabic characters should be included in utf-8 if I'm not mistaking. So your html should look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: I add it but it dose not help me. Do you have any else idea?

Comment: @muniaali You should check what encoding your browser detects. What webserver are you running? It can also set an encoding.

Comment: how to change the encoding of browser??I have changed the encoding of the server

Comment: @muniaali You don't want to change it in the browser, you want to know what it is.

Comment: how to know the browser encoding?? sorry for bothering you.and thanks in advance

Comment: @muniaali If you have Chrome, go to the network inspector and initial GET request - should read something like `content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8` - if not, your system is not sending utf-8.